# MSG 209 Ambiguous column name 'Partyname'

Tags: sql-server

I'm getting this error:

> Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Purchase_Bill, Line 13
>   Ambiguous column name 'Partyname'.

when running this T-SQL code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE Purchase_Bill
    @Invoiceno VARCHAR(30),
    @Partyname VARCHAR(50)
AS
    SELECT
        s.Address,
        s.Contactno,
        m.Purchasedate, m.Gstno, m.Invoiceno, m.Partyname, m.Tax
    FROM
        Tbl_Purchase_Party_Master s
    INNER JOIN
        Tbl_Master_Purchase_Save m ON s.Partyname = m.Partyname
    WHERE
        Invoiceno = @Invoiceno 
        AND Partyname = @Partyname
```

Comment: what image?. Anyway, better post the code, not an image of it

Comment: Please post text, but from error alone you are tying to use Partyname more then once in same context (select or where clause) you need to use an alias if using the same name more then once.

Comment: There are at least two tables that have a column named `Partyname` in your query. So, you must explicitly state which table it should come from in your query. You can fully qualify it with table.column or use an alias.

Comment: You just need to give the table alias in the where clause. In this case it doesn't matter which one you give, because you have inner joined the tables with that column.

Comment: #James Z How to solve it ? please refer as query i am beginner now.

Comment: "Ambiguous column name" pretty much always means you need to add the table/alias in front of your columns.  it's a good practice to always do this in any query that has join(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just added the alias to the columns that would be ambiguous which were in this line

```
where Invoiceno=@Invoiceno and Partyname=@Partyname
```

Here's the modified proc.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


Alter proc Purchase_Bill
@Invoiceno varchar(30),
@Partyname varchar(50)
As
select s.Address,
  s.Contactno,
  m.Purchasedate,m.Gstno,m.Invoiceno,m.Partyname,m.Tax
from Tbl_Purchase_Party_Master s
inner join Tbl_Master_Purchase_Save m
  on s.Partyname = m.Partyname
where m.Invoiceno=@Invoiceno and m.Partyname=@Partyname


GO
```